# SignalR.Redis and ServiceStack.Redis in the same web app

Tags: redis, servicestack, signalr

I am using SignalR.Redis and ServiceStack.Redis in my web application.  I noticed that SignalR.Redis uses the Booksleeve redis client and of course ServiceStack.Redis has its own client code.

Is it alright to use both of these in the same project? Obviously it will work, but it seems like it might be a bad practice to be using multiple redis clients (and therefore multiple redis connections) from the same app.  Should I implement a SignalR backplane that uses ServiceStack.Redis client so all my code is using the same client or does it not matter?

Will a ServiceStack.Redis backplane for SignalR work as well since ServiceStack.Redis is not an asynchronous client like Booksleeve is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no technical issue for not using ServiceStack.Redis and Booksleeve in the same code-base, each just encapsulates their own (very light) tcp socket connections to a back-end redis-server with no code-sharing or state mutation between the libraries.

Comment: It looks fairly simple to write a ServiceStack.Redis backend for SignalR. Do you think the ServiceStack.Redis client might cause scalability issues in SignalR since it's not an async client?

Comment: Also, I understand that there isn't any technical issue and that they will work together without issues. But my question was more, would it be better if they were both using the same client? Would it be worth the trouble of creating a new SignalR backend?

Comment: Is it worth the trouble? is subjective, i.e. what would you gain? it doesn't seem like it would be much of a value-add, just 1 less external dependency.

Comment: I guess I am just thinking that having less TCP connections open would be a good thing, but it seems obvious that you don't think it's an issue at all and I should move on, eh?

Comment: You wouldn't have less open tcp connections, they'd just be managed by different libraries. If it's simple to do it then may be a great learning exercise in using both libraries, just technically the only benefit I see is one less external dependency to manage. We also use both ServiceStack.Redis and Booksleeve in the same project at work, there's no friction in having both.